# How to pause Firefox of invisible GUI sessions?

Tags: linux, firefox

I have got a not-so-new Linux machine (Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon) with several users. These users always work locally at the same screen/keyboard, one after the other. They tend not to log out of their GUI sessions (X sessions?), and they usually leave Firefox open on random web pages.

This causes permanent CPU load by all the Firefox instances of the invisible GUI sessions.

Is there a way to pause a process like Firefox, when the GUI session is invisible (when the screen saver is active or another user is working)?

**Update:** I will now test the [Auto Tab Discard add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard).

Comment: @conualfy But my users tend not to log out.

Comment: @RobertPollak  I guess you can try it on screen lock: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock

Comment: @conualfy So the lock screen script should call `killall -s SIGTSTP firefox` (and the same with all its 'Web Content' processes), but how would Firefox be restarted when unlocking the screen?